# Java Regex .* usage

Tags: java, regex

```
.*[A-Z].*
```

Here A-Z means any letter from Capital A to Z.
What is the purpose of using `.*` starting and beginning.

Please Explain above regex code

Comment: Have you googled it ? Search regex syntax ?  https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+syntax dozen of answers in a second

Comment: its an attempt to use a `.matches(...)` as a `.find(...)`. As in _"does this text contain any A-Z somewhere?"_ So it allows arbitrary stuff before and after.

Answer (score 1):

. means match any character in regular expressions. * means zero or more occurrences of the single regex preceding it.